# Globally available variables with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global, angular-services

We are in the process of migrating our webapp to Angular.js. Traditionally, we created a global object named `app` and used it to store functions, variables, etc. that were used globally. For example, the active user's name and avatar might be stored in `app.user`.

With the transition to angular, `app` is no longer just an object, it is an angular app module. What is the **correct** way to store data globally like this in an Angular mindset? It could be completely different, that's fine. I just want to make sure we do it correctly.

I would do something as simple as `app.global = {};` and use `app.global` around the site, but if the angular API ever changes to use a property named `global`, it would be a nightmare to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is fairly allergic to global variables. I would recommend using a [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services) (e.g. `UserDataService`) to hold this data and injecting it where it is needed (like in a controller).

Your service will be a singleton that can be accessed wherever it is injected.

Comment: I did try writing a Service that returned a blank object that could be manipulated. But maybe it would be a better idea to make it more specialized, as global variables really shouldn't be used excessively. This could result in quite a few services though. Is that still good practice? I should also mention that we are loading the values of these variables in our Django template file, which means the services will almost always be forced to load anyway. (We store certain AJAX urls, etc.)

Comment: Lots of small services (small, modular, reusable pieces in general) is precisely the goal of angular. Make them, and inject where needed! It keeps your code clean and makes for easy testing. I don't know much about your project, but even if you're using them alot, I would still recommend the separation you get by using small services.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. One last question then. Assuming I define the service in a file (services.js), is it possible to load and set the variables in the service without creating a controller specifically for this purpose? Something like angular.module('app').service('MyNewService'). That doesn't seem to work, and the docs imply that you need a controller to load the service. That seems silly.

Comment: You do need a controller to use the service. Services exist to be used by controllers (or resources or other services). To my knowledge, they are not used independently.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be to provide the value or function to angular's dependency injector via `Module.value` or `Module.constant`. See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module

Answer (score -2):

Well, you can also set it in rootScope as:

```
var app = angular.module('appName'){
   //other codes removed
}); 

app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.globalVariable = 'hello'; //global variable
});
```

Now you can access the globalVariable

Comment: True, but it is fairly difficult to access the $rootScope whenever you want, isn't it? If I just wanted it in a template or directive for example. Having to use app.run is a bit inconvenient.